# "ignore" property in hosting of firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

A typical hosting config is like this:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
```

So firebase will deploy everything under "`build`" folder. In that case, my question is why we still consider to ignore "`\**/node_modules/\**`" since "`node_modules`" is out of "`build`"?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case for your setup, but not necessarily for everyone else.  It might be that a particular webpack build puts a node_modules folder in the deployment root.

If this particular ignore isn't relevant for your build, then feel free to remove it.  But for others, it might be saving a lot of unnecessary time and space.